# httpd does not work with mod_fcgid

Tags: httpd, centos7, mod-fcgid

based on the answer here, centos does not have a mod_fastcgi rpm, but a mod_fcgid could be used for most similar purposes. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12005137/centos-mod-fastcgi

Therefore, I installed mod_fcgid using yum on centos7, and adding

```
LoadModule fastcgi_module modules/mod_fcgid.so
```

instead of

```
LoadModule fastcgi_module modules/mod_fastcgi.so
```

into the `httpd.conf`

and /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_fcgid.so do exist.

however, when run `service httpd start`, it says:

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

and

```
journalctl -xe
Mar 17 17:19:15 open-kvm-app63 kill[31039]: kill: cannot find process ""
Mar 17 17:19:15 open-kvm-app63 systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Mar 17 17:19:15 open-kvm-app63 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
```

then I delete this line int the conf file, `httpd` could start again.
And I wonder why httpd could not start with that configuration, thanks.